# Why $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x+1}-1}$ can be written as $\sqrt{x+1}+1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've evaluated the first formula on $W|A$ and it says that $\sqrt{x+1}+1$ is an alternate form to the first expression. I just don't see how it's possible.

The first thing I imagined was to write:

$$\frac{x}{\sqrt{x+1}-1}=x^1(\sqrt{x+1}-1)^{-1}$$

But it doesn't seems to give me much insight.

Comment: Rationalize the denominator: multiply top and bottom by $\sqrt{x+1} + 1$. Observe also that $(\sqrt{x+1} + 1)(\sqrt{x+1} - 1) = x$.

Comment: Multiply numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{x+1}+1$. The logic why you should do this is to remove the square root in the denominator. Use $(A-B)(A+B)=A^2-B^2$.

Answer (score 5):

Just multiiply by 1, in a special form :
$$
\frac{x}{\sqrt{x+1}-1} \cdot 1 = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x+1}-1} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{x+1}+1}{\sqrt{x+1}+1} = \cdots
$$
Can you take it from here ?

Answer (score 4):

Note: the two functions of $x$ are NOT equal, because they have different domains.

$\frac{x}{\sqrt{x+1}-1}$ has domain $[-1,0)\cup(0,\infty)$

$\sqrt{x+1}+1$ has domain $[-1,\infty)$

Hence the former is not defined at $x=0$, while the latter is.

However, on all the points of their mutual domain, they agree; the calculation involves multiplying by the conjugate of the denominator, and may be found in the other answers.

Comment: That discontinuity is easily removed with its limiting value, though.

Comment: @BrianTung, sure, but this makes it no longer a precalculus question.

Comment: Hmm, that's definitely something I learned pre-calculus.  Your mileage may vary, of course.

Comment: In the U.S., limits and continuity are covered in calculus.  Precalculus is more about functions, domain and range, etc.

Comment: I'm educated in the U.S.; lived here my entire life.  Again, your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply Numerator and denominator by $sqrt(x+1) + 1 $ and see ...

Answer (score 1):

Write x/(((x+1)^(1/2))-1) as (x+1-1)/(((x+1)^(1/2))-1)

Comment: Quite hard to read

Answer (score 1):

With the assumption that the root is well defined and the denominator is nonzero we can write:

$\frac{x}{\sqrt{x+1}-1}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x+1}-1}\times\frac {\sqrt{x+1}+1}{\sqrt{x+1}+1}={x(\sqrt{x+1}+1)\over {\sqrt {x+1}^2-1^2}}={x(\sqrt{x+1}+1)\over {x+1-1}}=\sqrt{x+1}+1$